# Sending objects over the wire in grails

Tags: grails

I am using the REST builder plugin to send request over HTTP from one Grails server to another.

Sender

```
restClient.get(path: "/shipping",
                query:[dress: dress]
```

Sender log:

```
2014-03-24 23:32:20,299 [main] DEBUG http.wire  - >> "GET /shipping?dress=MyDress(payPassId:2,+dateCreated:Mon+Mar+24+23:32:20+GMT+2014,+dateLastActive:Mon+Mar+24+23:32:20+GMT+2014,+nickName:null,+recipientName:null,+defaultAddress:null,+street1:null,+street2:null,+street3:null,+city:null,+state:null,+country:null,+postalCode:12345,+recipientPhoneNumber:null,+recipientPhoneNumberCountryCode:null) HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
```

Receiver tries to get dress object

```
MyDress mydress = params.dress;
```

Error message is:

Cannot cast object `'MyDress(payPassId:2,+dateCreated:Mon+Mar+24+23:32:20+GMT+2014,+dateLastActive:Mon+Mar+24+23:32:20+GMT+2014,+nickName:null,+recipientName:null,+defaultAddress:null,+street1:null,+street2:null,+street3:null,+city:null,+state:null,+country:null,+postalCode:12345,+recipientPhoneNumber:null,+recipientPhoneNumberCountryCode:null)' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'MyDress'`

Is there some magic API I am missing here?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/) the plugin that you're using?

Comment: Am using: groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of data is not compatible with Grails. You need either to send the data as `JSON` or to send them as individual params and create a new instance of your object with:

```
MyAddress instance = new MyAddress(params)
```

You're probably sending the `toString()` of your object instead of the data (the RESTClient probably needs a Map instead of MyDress).